# Session passed but cannot echo the whole content of session

Tags: php, session

This has to do with my previous post which is

[Session not passed and active session is what it gets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23479841/session-not-passed-and-active-session-is-what-it-gets)

Now here's my problem. Everything went out real fine but it does not echo the hole content of the session in my table.

Here's the query timekeepingquery.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","leavecalendar");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM timekeeping ");
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
if(!empty($row)){
$_SESSION['row'] = $row;

header("location:timekeepinglogs.php");
}

?>
```

now here's the table in (timekeepinglogs.php)

```
<table width="10%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" style="width: 897px;">
<tr>
<td>
<table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"  class="form-table">
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdclass"><strong>Full Name</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdclass"><strong>Clock In</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdclass"><strong>Clock Out</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdclass"><strong>Date</strong></td>

<!--<?php
//while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
?>-->

<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $row['fullname']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $row['actualstart']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $row['actualend']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo date("m-d-Y", strtotime($row['createddate'])); ?></td>

</tr>

<!--<?php
}
?>-->
</table>


  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

But it shows in the table the last record only. I want to get all the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM timekeeping ");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
if(!empty($row)){
    $_SESSION['row'] = $row;
    header("location:timekeepinglogs.php");
}
```

When you fix your indenting, it's pretty obvious. You redirect as soon as you've put one row in the session. Move the redirect outside of the loop and conditional, and add braces to your while loop.

Edit: You'd also need to save each row in a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: @cmorrissey That is what I said. That is the OP's code, with the indenting making it obvious.

Answer (score 2):

You are redirecting the first time through the loop.  Aside from that you would be overwriting `$_SESSION['row']` each time:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
    $_SESSION['rows'][] = $row;
}
header("location:timekeepinglogs.php");
exit;
```

Then you need to loop over the `$_SESSION['rows']` array (assuming you have `session_start()` in `timekeepinglogs.php`:

```
<?php
foreach($_SESSION['rows'] as $row)
{
?>

<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $row['fullname']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $row['actualstart']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $row['actualend']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo date("m-d-Y", strtotime($row['createddate'])); ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>
```

**But  cmorrissey brings up a good point... Why are you doing this?**

Comment: Actually I'm making it like this so that I can filter it in the future. Because on my previous coding, The data was there so as the query making it impossible to filter.

Comment: This one actually works but I still came across an error. Actually there are only 3 or 4 rows of data in mysql table but with this code it duplicates those 3 rows 3 times also. What will I do